# VSCode not rendiring ipywidgets

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create 2 buttons with ipywidgets but vscode is not rendering it, as you can see in the image bellow

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Kmq.png)

Any ideias on how to fix it?

I have tried ipywidgets 7.7.1,7.7.2 and 8.1.0 and none of them work.

Here's the code

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

messages = Queue()
recordings = Queue()

record_button = widgets.Button(
    description='Record',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='success',
    tooltip='Record',
    icon='microphone'
)

stop_button = widgets.Button(
    description='Stop',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='warning',
    tooltip='Stop',
    icon='stop'
)

output = widgets.Output()
display(record_button, stop_button, output)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. I cannot reproduce this. it works fine for me with VS Code 1.81.1, ipython 8.11.0, jupyer 1.0.0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a delay, please click the run triangle button repeatedly or `Run All` above.

[image]

Also make sure that the jupyter output option is selected as shown in the figure below

[image]

[image]

You can also use the following command to update the required packages to the latest.

```
pip install --upgrade package_name
```